# Error while parsing Date in Spark scala program

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am parsing a date by the following statements and the spark program is throwing error while execution.

```
import java.time.LocalDate
val filterDate = "2017-06-26"
val filter = LocalDate.parse(load_dt)
```

I used filter variable in filtering records from a data frame column.

```
val df1 = spark.sql("select * from tableA")
val df2 = df1.filter(load_dt = filter)
```

while executing the above program it threw following error

```
User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '(tableA.`load_dt` = ((2017 - 6) - 26))' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '(tableA.`load_dt` = ((2017 - 6) - 26))' (date and int).; line 1 pos 0;
```

I couldn't understand why it is looking at (2017 - 6) separately and (-26) separately.

could anyone please help
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark's DataFrame API doesn't have encoders for `java.time.LocalDate`, but since your `load_dt` column is already of type `java.sql.Date`, you don't need to convert your `filterDate` to `LocalDate`.  Another issue is that `===` should be used for equality check in your `filter` condition, like in the following example:

```
val filterDate = "2017-06-26"

val df1 = Seq(
  (1, java.sql.Date.valueOf("2017-06-25")),
  (2, java.sql.Date.valueOf("2017-06-26")),
  (3, java.sql.Date.valueOf("2017-06-27"))
).toDF("id", "load_dt")

val df2 = df1.filter($"load_dt" === filterDate)

df2.show
+---+----------+
| id|   load_dt|
+---+----------+
|  2|2017-06-26|
+---+----------+
```

[UPDATE]

Per your comment, if `filterColumn` and `filterValue` are provided as variables:

Using Spark SQL:

```
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("df1Table")

val tableName = "df1Table"
val filterColumn = "load_dt"
val filterValue = "2017-06-26"

val df2 = spark.sqlContext.sql(
  "select * from " + tableName + " where " + filterColumn + " = '" + filterValue + "'"
)

// Alternative: use string interpolation `s"..."`
val df2 = spark.sqlContext.sql(
  s"select * from $tableName where $filterColumn = '$filterValue'"
)
```

Using Spark DataFrame API:

```
val df2 = df1.select("*").where(col(filterColumn) === filterValue)
```

Comment: Thanks Leo for your answer. I was able to execute the program with '===' and passing filterDate = "2017-06-26" inside the program. I have an issue now that when I am trying to pass the filterValue as argument from spark-submit it is not reading it correctly as I cannot give the date under quotes " ". like val df = spark.sql("select * from" + tableName + "where"  + filterColumn + " = " + " ' " + filterValue  + " ' "). I already defined table name and filterColumn before this statement in program.

Comment: It looks like you're missing/mis-placing spaces in composing your SQL statement.  Please see my updated answer.